# Why does using the outDir with an absolute path in msbuild destroy publishing clickonce

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2013, clickonce

If I just do

msbuild my.sln /t:publish

I get all my sub projects built in their own folders and my clickonce projects build as

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        23.04.2014     18:02            Application Files
-a---        23.04.2014     18:02     425968 setup.exe
-a---        23.04.2014     18:02       5730 WeinGartner.WeinCad.application
```

in a nice little folder. However when I do

```
msbuild my.sln /t:publish /outDir:"c:\a\bin"
```

I end up with everything dumped in one folder ( which I want ) but I'm missing `setup.exe`. The `.application` file is there. What's the trick here?

Comment: Try to call msbuild using a [logger parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx). Investigate the log file and you might get a clue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the setup.exe file. Just use the .application file.